# How to get colormap color to use in a \textcolor?

Tags: color

I have a `tabular` with a few values, which I want to color-code with `\textcolor`. The color scheme is given by a `colormap`:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    A & \textcolor{mypink}{0.64} & \textcolor{myred}{1.64} & \textcolor{myyellow}{2.64} & \textcolor{myblue}{4.64}   \\ \hline
    B & 125000 & 100000 & 50000 & 0  \\ \hline
    C & 1.23 & 2.00 & 2.00 & 2.00  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-1.5cm]
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
scale only axis,
height=0pt,
width=0pt,
colormap/jet,
colorbar,
point meta min=0,
point meta max=150000,
colorbar style={
    height=2cm,
    ytick={0, 50000,100000,150000}
}]
\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

where `mypink`, `myblue`, `myred`, and `myyellow` are defined as

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mypink}{RGB}{219, 48, 122}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{219, 0, 0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{0, 255, 244}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0, 0, 122}
```

The colors of line A are based on a metric shown in line B, which ranges from `0` to `150000`, the scale of the colormap. I want to define textcolors based on that metric, and remove line B from the table. For example, instead of saying `mypink` on the cell, I'd use a `color{125000}` (where `125000` is the color metric of that cell) to obtain the appropriate color based on the color map.

How can I do this? I've seen suggestions to `index of colormap` or `color of colormap`, but I'm not sure how to use these here.